# Check Group of Radiobutton is selected or not

Tags: c#, wpf

So i have a Group of RadioButtons in a StackPanel, now i want to check if something is selected or not.

```
            var programme = programm_wahl.Children.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.IsChecked.HasValue && r.IsChecked.Value);

        if (programme.IsChecked == true ) {..}
```

It is throwing me a error that programme is null i tried also `programme.IsChecked != null && programme.IsChecked == true` both ways not working.

Comment: Maybe a selector and hence listbox would suit your purposes better. That has selected item which you can bind. You can template your items to look however you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is shown because the `programme` variable is returning a null value.

Meaning the object `.IsChecked` is not available.

Try this:

```
if (programme != null && programme.IsChecked == true) {...}
```